# Reproducing kernel hilbert space norm as smoothness functional

Tags: kernel-trick, functional-data-analysis, manifold-learning

Let $K:X \times X \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ be a Mercer kernel with an associated RKHS $H$ then the norm $|f|_H^2$ can be used as a way to ensure that $f$ is smooth in $H$. If i understand correctly, since $f = \sum_{i=1}^m a_i K_{x_i}$ then by minimizing $|f|_h^2$, we are trying to minimize the coefficients $a_i$. Am i understanding it correctly ? The reference paper can be found at https://www.jmlr.org/papers/v7/belkin06a.html

Comment: You can "minimize the coefficients" only by having them all simultaneously approach $-\infty;$ or you can minimize their magnitudes only by setting them all to zero.  Neither describes what is being done, though.  By optimizing the norm you are *varying* the coefficients, not minimizing them.

Comment: Then how can the RKHS norm of $f$ be used as a regularization term as described in the paper as a smoothness functional ?